# SQL query returning empty set

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
| BookID | BookTitle                      | NumberOfPages | NoOfCopies |
+--------+--------------------------------+---------------+------------+ 
|      1 | The Help                       |           444 |          4 |
|      2 | The Catcher in the Rye         |           277 |         10 |  
|      3 | Crime and Punishment           |           545 |          2 |
|      4 | The Brothers Karamazov         |           795 |          1 |
|      5 | A Crown of Wishes              |           369 |         12 |
|      6 | The Fireman                    |           752 |          3 |
|      7 | Fahrenheit 451                 |           174 |          9 |
|      8 | The Hobbit                     |           366 |          1 |
|      9 | Lord of Emperors               |           560 |          4 |
|     10 | Holy Bible: King James Version |          1590 |         11 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I insert a *book title* and expect it to return the book id, it always returns an empty set
so far, I have tried these queries.->book_info is the name of the table:

```
select BookID from book_info where ucase(BookTitle) = ' THE HELP% ';
select BookID from book_info where BookTitle = ' The Help   ';
select BookID from book_info where lcase(trim(BookTitle) = 'the help';
```

but none of them worked.

**Note I don't rely on sql in my job.**

Comment: Are you after 'LIKE' ?

Comment: you should use like

Comment: It's the same @Strawberry.

Comment: Query 3 would work with another ) after booktitle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use like if you want to use "%"

when you use "=" you need to sure it is same. even space also count

```
  select BookID from book_info where BookTitle LIKE 'THE HELP%';
```

Comment: It worked , but can you please explain why it did or link me to the sql manual i would appreciate it.

Comment: you can find simple use here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is with the operator you are using and the value you are function you are expecting from it, `=` operator checks for the exact match that's why your queries are returning no records:

```
select BookID from book_info where ucase(BookTitle) = ' THE HELP% ';
select BookID from book_info where BookTitle = ' The Help   ';
select BookID from book_info where lcase(trim(BookTitle) = 'the help';
```

And one more thing that is:

> MySQL queries are not case-sensitive by default.

So you don't need to add the string methods here to change the values case.

We usually use the `%` with `LIKE` only like this:

```
select BookID from book_info where ucase(BookTitle) LIKE '%THE HELP%';
```

In this query `LIKE %THE HELP%` will match all the string having `THE HELP` in them;